# Deactivate WooCommerce registration email for programmatically created accounts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm currently looking for a way to deactivate the WooCommerce/ Wordpress account registration email for accounts that are created programmatically in a custom function:

```
function myFunction($user_email){
    wc_create_new_customer($user_email)
}
```

This can be switched on and off globally in the WooCommerce backend. However I only want it turned off when called in that specific function and leave it active when customers create account via the my account page or checkout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may use page slug condition with wordpress is_page() function:

// When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "checkout" is being displayed.

```
if(is_page( 'checkout' )){

function myFunction(){ //this function will be activated.

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. With this you can in fact identify pages. However this does not manipulate the wc_create_new_customer function in any way.

What I'm looking for is to call the above mentioned function and under certain conditions deactivate the new account email which is being send.